# How can I convert this Java regular expression to Go's regular expression syntax?

Tags: java, regex, go, clojure

I'm trying to convert this Java regular expression to Go's regular expression syntax:

> [:]?([\D&&[^/]].*/)?(/|[\D&&[^/]][^/]*)

This regular expression is the regex for matching Clojure keywords, taken from the JVM Clojure compiler.

Comment: Can you provide some input values and expected results?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It should be

```
var pattern = regexp.MustCompile(`:?([^/\d].*/)?(/|[^\d/][^/]*)`)
```

The pattern `[\D&&[^/]]` means *any non-digit but a `/`*, and it can be expressed with an extended negated character class `[^\d/]`.

Comment: Please provide an example string to find matches in if it does not work for you.

Comment: Fantastic! Thanks for the super speedy response time :)

Comment: You are welcome. You can learn about that Java character class syntax at [this page](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/regex/char_classes.html). This `[\D&&[^/]]` is an example of a character class subtraction.